# WPF - Set Keyboard Focus to ListView Item like Tab does

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, focus, listviewitem

I have a Listview amongst other controls in my WPF form. When I tab between controls and the ListView is focused, automatically a ListView Item is focused, not the ListView itself, which allows to move between Items with the keyboard.

I want the same behavior when a user clicks on a blank area in the ListView. So I created a Click event for the ListView, but do not know which code to execute. I have tried;

```
ListView.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(ListView);
```

But always the ListView itself is focused, which makes sense I guess.. Setting the ListView to focusable = false completely disables focusing, including the items and focusing with tabbing around also does not work anymore.

How can I recreate the Tab focus behavior in my OnClick event?

Comment: Did you try to focus/select the first `ListViewItem` instead of the `ListView` itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to focus the first item in the `ListView`:

```
ListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
ListViewItem lvi = ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListViewItem;
if (lvi != null)
    lvi.Focus();
```

Comment: thanks for that. I cannot imagine however that this is executed when you hit tab to focus a ListView, right? Is there no function that just calls a 'tab focus'  to the ListView? I just tested it and it does work perfectly though!

Comment: You don't want to cal 'tab focus' on the ListView. You want to focus the ListViewItem. And a mouse click isn't the same thing as tabbing so I don't really see why this approach wouldn't work in this case?

Comment: It works perfectly, Just wondering if this code is actually executed for the ListView when you tab focus it, that's all..
The only issue I have now is that when you click on an actual treeview item, this code is also executed. I tried if (sender,getType() != typeof(TreeViewItem), but I guess they fire independently

Comment: That's is probably a matter of how you are handling your "click" event but that's another story. Please ask a new question of you have another issue.